# How to recover/reinstall Grandstream GXP phones firmware?

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx

I bought a Grandstream IP phone recently and tried to go through first installation, but suddenly most of SIP settings and also settings of firmware update server disappeared and I even can't login to configuration panel via default credentials. I pressed "Erase Custom SCR" as one of my attempts to force it to update itself. Then every time I try to erase the user data by holding 1 + 9 keys, the device reboots again.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you performed a "factory reset"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, this company's devices disable part of the settings as soon as they connect to the update server from some countries.
I finally reinstalled the firmware locally via DTMF (fortunately set before). The issue was that I had not a "factory reset" option. Even this option strangely does not work perfectly and does not return all the settings to the default state.

Comment: Honestly, when I worked with Grandstream phones, they proved to be a cheap crap isn't worth buying. Even (cheap too) Yealinks or D-Links proved to be more robust.